# Where do I get the Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM) driver for OS X 10.8.1 (Mountain Lion)?

Tags: android, intel, android-virtual-device, osx-mountain-lion, hardware-acceleration

I am trying to install the latest driver - version 1.0.1 (R2) from Intel's website. It states that the driver is supported on Intel-based Macs with Mac OS X 10.6 and later (32/64-bit). But when I try to install it, I get an error stating that my Mac doesn't meet the minimum requirements.

Please note I have a Mid 2010 Macbook (White) which does support Intel VT-x and is enabled. I also had this driver installed and working on my Macbook when it was running Snow Leopard (10.6.x). So, I'm guessing this has something to do with Intel not testing their driver with Mountain Lion :)

Does anybody have any tips on getting this installed or contacting Intel to provide this feedback?

Thanks!

P.S.: wanted to tag this post with "haxm" tag but couldn't. Can someone with higher rep please tag it? TIA!

Comment: Seems to work on my 2009 MBP with 10.8.1.

Comment: Does it give you any further info about which specific minimum requirements your machine doesn't meet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a small bug/error/whatever in the HAXM installer that causes the script which checks the requirements to report a false result. Fix:

1. Download the DMG from the [Intel website](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager/)
2. Open the DMG in Disk Util and convert it into a Disk Image that is writable
3. Mount the DMG
4. Open Terminal, change to `/Volumes/IntelHAXM_1.0.1/IntelHAXM_1.0.1.mpkg/Contents/Resources` (Change path if necessary).
5. Apply the patch (see below) to the file `haxm-req.sh`.
6. Close Terminal, run the installer package as usual.

The patch:

```
--- haxm-req.sh.old 2012-10-09 11:26:35.000000000 +0200
+++ haxm-req.sh 2012-10-09 11:27:01.000000000 +0200
@@ -4,7 +4,7 @@
 "$fullpath/haxm-check"
 result=$?
 if ! [ $result -eq 0 ]; then
-   TRUE;
+   /usr/bin/true;
 else
-   FALSE;
+   /usr/bin/false;
 fi
```

To apply the patch, run `patch -p0 < haxm-req.patch` if you saved it in the file `haxm-req.patch` in the `Resources` directory.